# Django Rest Framework - Extending the existing User model and saving it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Profile` model, that is connected to `user` by `OneToOne` field. How can I alter my process of profile creation in order to associate user with profile ? I use token auth.

```
class ProfileCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
          model = Profile
          fields = [
              'name',
              'age',
              'heigth',
              'location',
          ]

class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileCreateSerializer
```

Comment: Is the `user` to be assigned the current user i.e  `request.user`?

Comment: I think it can work. I have to get user from request.user and pass to user field of profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the currently loggedin user, you can override the `perform_create()` method of the `ProfileCreateAPIView`.

In that method, you can pass the `user` argument with value as `request.user`. DRF will use this extra value along with the fields defined in the serializer to create `Profile` instance.

```
class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):        
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user) # pass the user field
```